# SOA feature in netbeans 7.4

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans, soa

Ok I am doing project on web services where I plan to implement based on JAX-WS.However i have an issue which I think is about composing services. And after searching on Internet i found WS-BPEL will allow me to do that. I am using netbeans 7.4 but i do not have the SOA feature in it. So now my question is.?

Is there any other method for doing service composition?

is there any link where i can download the SOA plugin for netbeans 7.4?

Or any tutorial which can gimme information on any new technologies which i can use for service composition using existing netbeans 7.4?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can remember the SOA plugin got removed from Netbeans around the time Oracle took it over. Last time I used the SOA plugin was in release 6.5.So I suspect you might be out of luck.

I would suggest you look at Apache Camel for doing this type of work. Or look at the WSO BPEL plugin for Eclipse.

Comment: can apache camel be integrated with netbeans

Comment: yeah but I would suggest you use the FuseIDE or eclipse rather.

Comment: okay.. I guess i have no option. Cause the older versions of netbeans cannot be downloaded and have bugs